# Solving the differential equation for general solution.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, curves

Find general solution of x(1-xlny)y' +y=0     my attempt: I tried substituting 1-xlny=t and rephrased the given equation in terms of t and x but couldn't solve thereafter. Help appreciated and other approaches are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the given differential equation as
$$xdy+ydx-x^2\ln ydy=0 \implies d(xy)-x^2\ln ydy=0$$
Dividing by $x^2y^2$,
$$\frac{d(xy)}{(xy)^2}=\frac{\ln ydy}{y^2}$$
Integrating both sides,
$$-\frac{1}{xy}+C=\int\frac{\ln ydy}{y^2}$$
Applying Integration by Parts to the second integral gives,
$$-\frac{1}{xy}+C=-\frac{\ln y}{y}+\int{\frac{dy}{y^2}}=-\frac{\ln y}{y}-\frac{1}{y}$$
$$\therefore \frac{1}{x}=1+\ln y+Cy$$

Answer (score 1):

$$x(1-x\ln y)y' +y=0 $$
$$x(1-x\ln y)=-yx' $$
It's Bernoulli's equation:
$$x'y+x=x^2 \ln y$$
And it's also separable:
$$\dfrac {d(xy)}{dy}=x^2 { \ln y}$$
$$\dfrac {d(xy)}{(xy)^2}=\dfrac { \ln y}{y^2}dy$$
Integrate.